# Performance testing of the application with SMS OTP

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

I wanted to test an API which needs OTP to proceed further.. i am using another API to fetch the OTP, but it wouldnt be returned in the response, inturn it will be sent to the mobile..

My question is that , how to fetch the OTP from phone message and continue the test. challenge is that i cant disable security or use any API for this as it will be sent to the phone number

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to get SMS from the real phone you would need to use phone automation framework like [Appium](https://appium.io/).

There is [Appium Java Client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) which you can use in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) in order to control your mobile device and read the SMS with the OTP

But this approach would be **extremely** slow and the maximum throughput will be set to Appium execution speed.

So you could rather think of using [SMS Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) and a library like [jSMPP](https://jsmpp.org/) or use an [online SMS receiving service providing API](https://rapidapi.com/blog/sms-apis-send-texts/) and "normal" JMeter Post-Processors.